# Javascript Interface for Sound Cloud

Tags: javascript, sdk, soundcloud

I am building a site for someone who wants to have a sound cloud player on his site, but wants it skinned up to look integrated into the site.  For the moment, I am using a script which will create an iframe element within a hidden div (which auto plays), and when a new item is selected to play, it clears the div, and replaces it with a new iframe element.

The next phase for the project requires a bit more integration though. I have been searching for javascript sound cloud integration, but all it seems to provide is creating a simple link that will play and pause the track (only on the users request) with a little bit of javascript to coax it into playing immediately.

Are there any other integrations for sound cloud via javascript that would allow for playing, pausing, stopping and getting information about the current play position (like from an event), as well as other events (like onstart, onstop, onpositionchange, etc)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah ha, found the answer. Have a look on: http://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/sdks#javascript

The `SC.stream` seems to provide all the answers